# Is there something in a debug.log from 2011 that would tell me if there are BTC in an old wallet.dat?

Tags: wallet

I took an old laptop out of storage today because I recalled trying to mine BTC years ago. I remember giving up quickly because, whatever the UI was, it showed that I had mined 0. I'd like to confirm that.

Is there anything in any of these files that would confirm that there's 0 BTC in these? debug.log seems to be the only plaintext file.

Date modified on these files are in the range of 05/2011 ~ 06/2011

```
/user/AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin
-database/    (9MB)
-.lock        (0KB)
-__db.001    
-__db.002    
-__db.003    
-__db.004    
-__db.005    
-__db.006    
-addr.dat    (18MB)
-blk0001.dat (279MB)
-blkindex.dat(133MB)
-db.log      (0KB)
-debug.log   (3MB)
-wallet.dat  (104KB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in this case (the easiest approach):

- Copy `wallet.dat` to a new directory called `Bitcoin` in `%appdata%`
- Run latest Bitcoin core
- Open the console and do
- `dumpwallet C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\wallet.txt`
- Quit Core and delete your new Bitcoin directory. (Don't forget to delete it, it might become larger than `100 MB`, to save space)
- Save my [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DesWurstes/ce0e1727a53e4b1f6e808e2ef5801ece/raw/dda4eb0ac56ca72d36b5d7364e722bda096b3d1f/dumpwallet.html) with Ctrl + S and name it `dumpwallet.html`. Open it in your browser. Copy the wallet.txt output here so that only the private keys are listed.
- Import wallet to Electrum: "New wallet > Import private keys > Copy from the webpage output"

Then you can see your balance or spend from it.

The tedious approach is to use `db_dump` of `db-util` to dump all the transactions and calculate the final balance by yourself. I would not bother doing it this way.

Comment: Thank you. The old computer is extremely slow. Can I move these files to a new computer and do this, or is there something tied to that machine?

Comment: Yes, you just need to copy `wallet.dat` to new folder named `Bitcoin` in `%appdata%` on your new computer. Then when you launch Core, it'll show `0 BTC` however that doesn't mean anything, so just follow the steps above then. I can also write in more details on "import wallet to electrum" once you come to that step

Comment: Thanks. Was able to follow these steps. Looks like the best block at time of backup was mined on 2010-03-21, and there are 1000 lines in here. One with label= and the rest with reserve=1. If I did this correctly, I'm looking in Electrum and they indeed all have a balance of 0 and Tx of 0.

Comment: `reserve` means unused, so yes.

Comment: Thanks. When I run Bitcoin core, will it ask for a passcode? Because I don't have it.

Comment: @user114196 If the wallet.dat has one, yes.