# Inherited bitcoin. Want to sell. Have wallet.dat . Please help

Tags: sell-bitcoins

Inherited bitcoin. Want to sell. Have wallet.dat on my computer. How to sell the bitcoin in the wallet? Do I need a passcode ?

Comment: Is your computer Windows? You need to install Bitcoin Core first.

Comment: Steps here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101318/is-there-something-in-a-debug-log-from-2011-that-would-tell-me-if-there-are-btc/101319#101319