# My BTC hasn't shown up in my Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core

I transferred BTC to my wallet and it hasn't shown up. IT's been 6 weeks and still nothing. I transferred my funds from Binance and Binance is showing that the BTC has been send and received. Bitcoin Core is telling me that it needs to synchronize with the network and is 5 years and 4 months behind. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to retrieve my BTC? Thank you

Comment: Yes you either need to sync or dump your keys and use them in a different wallet: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/102078/38618

Answer (score 1):

> Bitcoin Core is telling me that it needs to synchronize with the network and is 5 years and 4 months behind. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to retrieve my BTC?

You have not synced bitcoin core full node yet.

If you want to check transactions associated with an address from this wallet or create unsigned transactions:

Create a watch-only wallet in [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#download) by using the last option '*Import bitcoin addresses or private keys*' while creating new wallet or you can create watch-only wallet in bitcoin core as well if you have it synced on other machine

If you want to sign and broadcast transactions using bitcoin core:

[signrawtransactionwithwallet](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/signrawtransactionwithwallet/)

[sendrawtransaction](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/sendrawtransaction/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not let core sync up the the network. Click on the 5 years behind bar at the bottom and it will bring up details on the sync process. Check what the estimated time to sync is. If there is no estimate then give it a few minutes, it can take some time to find peers after starting sometimes. If still no estimate, go to window>peers and see if there are more than a few peers, then see network tab to see if it is receiving data from the network.

If you are receiving data and have a "Estimate time left until synced", then you just have to leave the program running. It can only catch up if it is running.

If you close the program it will stop downloading block data and not be able to catch up. Keep it running and just wait a bit.

If you are not receiving data or have peers then we might need more information to help you. I don't know what your setup is.