# Recovering and transferring Bitcoin to new wallet

Tags: wallet

Question from a new bee.
I received a bitcoin in 2013.
That one is on my old computer with a Bitcoin wallet (version 0.8.1-win32).
It is visible and verified
Unfortunately this wallet still has over 4.000 days to sync.
And it takes ages to complete
Besides the fact that the old laptop keeps running out of storage space :-(

On my new computer I now have the wallet Bitcoin Core (version v0.21.0)

How can I move the Bitcoin from my old laptop to my new one?

As I said, I am a bit of a nitwit on this, so please do not make it to technical ;-)
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Bitcoin Core to Electrum:**

```
walletpassphrase "your_pass_phrase" "timeout"


dumpwallet "full path:dump_test1"
```

```
{
  "filename": "full path:dump_test1"
}
```

File with all the private keys dumped:

[image: dump_file]

[image: electrum-1]

I will use private key for one of the addresses, you can enter multiple private keys here.

```
Address: tb1qpc8wx9sec3s7sm3j949eeg2pj3e6n3df9c5w2u
Private Key: cRGkMQJfJiBhj1Fq83cNX4pUAerB1dJSJWkvfcDuGtqwb2M6L5WK
Derivation Path: m/0'/1'/21'
```

[image: electrum-pk]

[image: Address-history-electrum]

**Bitcoin Core to Bitcoin Core:**

Backup Wallet or copy `wallet.dat`

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core is not a general purpose wallet. I have instructions [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/101319/38618) to extract the private keys and import them to Electrum.

You can skip the first step there. Make sure to back up the `wallet.dat` though.