# How to move wallet.dat from Bitcoin Core into Electrum?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, wallet.dat

I've got a wallet.dat file from Bitcoin Core and I'd like to move that into electrum because I can't open Bitcoin Core as the syncing process takes forever and eventually fails. I also read that electrum won't read wallet.dat files. Is there any other way to do this?

I tried to run ...

```
$ bitcoin-cli dumpwallet "test"
```

but if I understand this correctly, I need to run bitcoind, and this fails on startup because of an error in debug.log like

```
LevelDB read failure: Corruption: block checksum mismatch
Fatal LevelDB error: Corruption: block checksum mismatch
You can use -debug=leveldb to get more complete diagnostic messages
Error: Error reading from database, shutting down.
```

In sum, I can't get the private keys using bitcoin core because upon startup, I get errors like the above.

Thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering and transferring Bitcoin to new wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102904/recovering-and-transferring-bitcoin-to-new-wallet)

Comment: I looked at that post which uses bitcoin-cli to dump, but I can't run bitcoind in order to run the cli and issue a dump. Am I understanding this correctly that bitcoind needs to run so that bitcoin-cli can connect to it?

Comment: I was not aware bitcoind is shutting down in few minutes. I thought it's just not synced. Maybe you can copy wallet.dat and try running bitcoin core on a different machine.