# Bitcoin cash not syncing the current block

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, block, bitcoin-cash

I have installed BCH "Bitcoin Unlimited Cash Edition  bucash1.7.0.0". Problem is the current block is not synced in our wallet server, the server is stuck at block "635258". How to rectify this problem, please suggests me

Answer (score 1):

BCH makes a hard fork every 6 months. Your node supports only the Nov 2019 hard fork. Update your Bitcoin Unlimited or it won't sync.

May 2020 upgrade: https://coinspice.io/ifp/bitcoin-cash-may-2020-upgrade/

Comment: @Manickam You're welcome. Please, next time, ask your Bitcoin Cash specific questions at reddit.com/r/btc. This website is only for Bitcoin related questions or questions Bitcoin users can directly benefit from.

Comment: if i upgrade BCH, then how to recover my funds in old version?

Comment: Create a backup of your `wallet.dat` and run the upgraded version. It should work. If it doesn't, you still have your backup so you wont have lost anything

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply

Comment: Is it possible to transfer funds from backup wallet to new wallet?

Comment: Run the dumpwallet command and do the last two steps too here https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/101319 to import your wallet to Electron Cash

Comment: We are using ubuntu server, how to dump the wallet and recreate a new bitcoincash core from the old one, please share those things if anyone knows asap.